# std vector of pointer to template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class something like :

```
template <class TYPE>
class Temp {
public:
    Temp(TYPE _val) : var(_val){};
    TYPE var;
};
```

I want to store the objects on this template class in a STL container say vector.

```
void print(vector<Temp<TYPE> *> & _vec) {
    for(unsigned short i = 0; i < _vec.size() ; i++)
       cout << " Value of stored variable is : " << (*_vec[i]).var << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector<Temp<TYPE> *> cont;
    Temp<int> t1(20);
    Temp<float> t2(1.4);
    cont.push_back(&t1);
    cont.push_back(&t2);
    return 0;        
}
```

I know that we cannot allocate a stl container without defining the type.
Is there any way around to get this done ? and I cannot use boost.variant.

Comment: If you cannot use a variant or `any` type, you need to provide a common base class and store pointers to that.

Comment: Why are you not able to use Boost.Variant? Have you considered implementing your own variant class (it is quite possible to do so in under 500 lines)?

Comment: Will it make any difference if the set of 'TYPE' is a fixed set ?

Answer (score 0):

Your options include:

- Giving the distinct instantiations of `Temp` a common base class (with a virtual destructor), then storing pointers to the base type in the `vector`.  You can then use `dynamic_cast<>` to check the run-time type of the stored objects, or you can add some type-indicating virtual function overridden in the derived instantiations.
- Writing your own discriminated union class, where an enum or int keeps track of the current type stored (if there's a fixed set).